# PHP File Upload(Any Type)

Tags: php, file-upload, upload

I am wondering if how can i change this to upload any kind of files(not just an image file). I am using these set of codes on my test project.

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="submit">
</form>

<?php

if ($_POST['submit']) {

$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

//Check if image file is a actual image or fake image

$check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);

if ($check !== false) {
    echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
    $uploadOk = 1;
} else {
    echo "File is not an image.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}

//Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" 
       && $imageFileType != "png" 
       && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
       && $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}

// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";

// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
         echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
}

?>
```

Can anyone help me, i tried removing the check if actual image , but it didnt help me.

Comment: just a heads up. This is a security risk!.. Trojans and other harmful files can be easily uploaded too you know

Comment: thanks sir,  ill be adding some security measures after i get to upload pdf files. thanks

Comment: .it is clear that you didn't write the above code/understand . If you could code to add restrictions for file upload, then you should be able to allow any type of file

Comment: Yes sir, i found it on the internet,

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if($_POST['submit']){

$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"],
    $target_file)) {
    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
} else {
    echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just delete image validation from your copied php code

```
<?php


 if($_POST['submit']){

 $target_dir = "uploads/";
 $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);

     if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], 
 $target_file)) {
         echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
     } else {
         echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
     }

 }
 ?>
```